# Generate a new variable in a list based on the values of two other columns

Tags: r, list, variables

I have a list of dataframes I would like to create a new variable, "County", based on the values of the "State" and "Zip Codes" columns. I know this is a situation where `lapply(df, transform)` is necessary.

```
State   Zip
OH  44141
OH  44056
OH  44131
NY  13035
NY  13035
NY  13056
```

This would work for a dataframe so I'm not sure how this translates to an application for a list

```
df$County[df$State == "OH" & df$Zip >= 44056 & df$Zip <= 44356]<- "Summit"
df$County[df$State == "NY" & df$Zip >= 1300 & df$Zip <= 13035]<- "Madison"
df$County[df$State == "NY" & df$Zip < 1300 | df$Zip > 13036] <- "Miscoded"
```

Comment: how is it possible to have a value that is greater than 2 and less than 2 at the same time?? There is no trinity in math... So you can not have a condition like `df$Zip < 1300 & df$Zip > 13036`... that is not logical in this world

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the following list.

```
df_list <- structure(list(NY = structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("NY", "OH"), class = "factor"), Zip = c(13035L, 
13035L, 13056L)), .Names = c("State", "Zip"), row.names = 4:6, class = "data.frame"), 
    OH = structure(list(State = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("NY", 
    "OH"), class = "factor"), Zip = c(44141L, 44056L, 44131L)), .Names = c("State", 
    "Zip"), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("NY", 
"OH"))
```

With `dplyr::mutate` and `purrr::map`, you can do something like

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_list %>% map(. %>% mutate(County = case_when(
    Zip >= 44056 & Zip <= 44356 ~ "Summit",
    Zip >= 1300 & Zip <= 13035 ~ "Madison",
    Zip < 1300 | Zip > 13036 ~ "Micoded",
    TRUE ~ NA_character_)))

# $NY
#   State   Zip  County
# 1    NY 13035 Madison
# 2    NY 13035 Madison
# 3    NY 13056 Micoded
# 
# $OH
#   State   Zip County
# 1    OH 44141 Summit
# 2    OH 44056 Summit
# 3    OH 44131 Summit
```

Answer (score 1):

**You seem to have a simple `data.frame`, so you can directly operate on the `data.frame` with `transform`; there is no need for `lapply` here.**

For code readability, I recommend a `tidyverse` solution using `case_when`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(County = case_when(
        State == "OH" & (Zip >= 44056 & Zip <= 44356) ~ "Summit",
        State == "NY" & (Zip >= 1300 & Zip <= 13035) ~ "Madison",
        State == "NY" & (Zip < 1300 | Zip > 13036) ~ "Micoded",
        TRUE ~ "Undefined"))
#  State   Zip  County
#1    OH 44141  Summit
#2    OH 44056  Summit
#3    OH 44131  Summit
#4    NY 13035 Madison
#5    NY 13035 Madison
#6    NY 13056 Micoded
```

In base R you could do

```
transform(df, County = ifelse(...))
```

with nested `ifelse` conditions, which is not as tidy (in my opinion).

Note that the `"Micoded"` condition from your code is incorrect; you need a logical OR: `Zip < 1300 | Zip > 13036`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "State   Zip
OH  44141
OH  44056
OH  44131
NY  13035
NY  13035
NY  13056")
```

Comment: My data is a list of dataframes, not just one dataframe which was why I was using lapply

Comment: @JamesWilson Your sample data suggested a `data.frame`. It's difficult to help with non-representative data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base R:

Looking at your data, it seems that the you cannot have a 44056 for NY for example. taking this assumption then you  can do:

```
> a=c(1299,13036,44055,44357)
> b=c("Miscoded","Madison","Miscoded","Summit")
> transform(df,county=b[findInterval(Zip,a)+1])


 State   Zip   county
1    OH 44141   Summit
2    OH 44056   Summit
3    OH 44131   Summit
4    NY 13035  Madison
5    NY 13035  Madison
6    NY 13056 Miscoded
```

if the assumption is not to be taken into consideration then you can do something like:

```
df1
State   Zip
1    OH 44141
2    OH 44056
3    OH 44131
4    NY 13035
5    NY 13035
6    NY 13056
7    NY 44141

df1$county<-b[findInterval(df1$Zip,a)+1]
transform(df1,
    county=ifelse(paste(State,county)%in%c("OH Summit","NY Madison"),county,"Miscoded"))

State   Zip   county
1    OH 44141   Summit
2    OH 44056   Summit
3    OH 44131   Summit
4    NY 13035  Madison
5    NY 13035  Madison
6    NY 13056 Miscoded
7    NY 44141 Miscoded
```

If you have a list of dataframes, just do:

```
m=function(df1){
df1$county<-b[findInterval(df1$Zip,a)+1]
transform(df1,
    county=ifelse(paste(State,county)%in%c("OH Summit","NY Madison")
           ,county,"Miscoded"))
}

lapply(df_list,m)
```